# Autoencoder with tied weights: bias?

Tags: neural-networks, bias, autoencoders, weights, ties

For some unsupervised learning problem, I need to train an autoencoder, so that I only have to store the encoder afterwards. However, I am not sure on how and if the bias weights can be tied.

To make myself more clear:
I have input $x\in R^d$, being encoded to a code $h\in R^{d'}$ using the encoding: $h=\sigma(Wx+b)$. The code is then used for the recostructruction with $y=\sigma(W'h+b')$, where $W'=W^T$ (tied weights) and $||y-x||^2$ is used as the minimization criterion. 
And now my question: Is there a similar way to tie the bias $b'$ according to some function of $W$ and $b$, so that after the training of the autoencoder, I can store the encoder parameters only? Or do I have to store the bias weights of the decoder as well? Also, if there are more layers on the encoder/decoder, does the same apply to their bias weights as well?

Answer (score 4):

There is no connection between the bias to hidden nodes and those to the reconstructed layer. To understand that this is not possible you can look at the dimensions of $b$ and $b'$. $b$ needs to be $d'$-dimensional and $b'$ is $d$-dimensional, one term for each node in the respective layer.

If you need to save $b'$ depends on what you want to do with your autoencoder. If you only want to perform dimensionality reduction there is really no need for the decoder part, the same goes if you want to use your autoencoder to initialize a deep neural network. However, if you want to build a deep autoencoder you would need the $b'$:s. And I guess it would not be that much of a trouble of saving them anyway.